# Designing a comfortable palace

Tags: aliens

The earth is under attack by aliens but they don't know it. It all began during the 1900's, a lone alien was sent to earth. His mission was to destabilise the earth's government so that the aliens can take over without any resistance. The alien, a master of disguise, lodged himself firmly in the government and started to cause havoc, untraceable to him of course. Through various means, he caused world wars 1 & 2, aided the development of the nuclear bomb and when the bomb was perfected, ignited world war 3 - the final war - apocalypse.

The humans have been reduced to his slaves and he is just waiting for the aliens to arrive take over. To show off his prowess, he has commissioned the creation of a mansion which will highlight the best things available on earth, according to him.

The mansion is going to be the most exquisite mansion ever built, displaying the riches and power he commands, extravagant. The pillars of the mansion are carved from ivory, inlaid with gold, studded with diamonds. Exquisite paintings hang from his wall. His wines are the best, the costliest. His food is made from animals long thought extinct. Over his one and a half century long stay, he has amassed all these things through various means and is now putting it on display.

He wants the mansion to be plush and comfortable, filled with elegant, wonderful unique things.

What are some of the things that have to be present in the mansion ?

Note: As it is a mansion, size limitations obviously apply. Also the alien abhors technology and wants to avoid it if possible but if he cannot then he wants the best.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for our site. It is very hard to judge answers to "what are some of the things that have to be present in the mansion?". How do we *objectively* decide whether any particular answer is useful or not in answering that? I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based ("answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise"), but will happily retract that close vote if someone can make a convincing argument for why the question should be left open.

Answer (score 2):

If these aliens want to conquer Earth, there must be something here they are interested in that isn't available elsewhere in uninhabited places/planets/space that would not require as much effort to conquer. Since this lone alien has waited patiently in the shadows for more than a hundred years without resorting to biological warfare or any such extreme methods that may have gotten him his results faster, it may mean that there is something he/they want preserved as it currently stands. Could be something biological, could be the desire for artistic and intelligent slaves, anything that would be lost should drastic methods be employed.

This alien would probably like to display all items that he/they would deem precious in light of this goal. Mere lumps of diamonds or gold may be seen as much less valuable than finely worked and creative pieces that would need intelligence and creativity to make. Food, wine, anything uniquely Earth, anything needing human sentience and feeling to create, would be more precious than any amount of the underlying raw material.

A probable list, please feel free to add:

- Artistic works of all sorts, modern and ancient: sculpture, paintings, functional art, live art such as drama, music, dance, movies
- Trees, plants, flowers, landscaped gardens, bonsai, ornamental fish ponds, pets, all rare
- Furniture of the best kind, made from different kinds of high-grade wood
- Slaves and servants 'of high-quality'
- Kitchens equipped with the finest foods and drinks and chefs and sommeliers to store/prepare them
- Wardrobes with wearable goods featuring furs, embroidery, human-worked fabrics.
- technological marvels: ipads, high-def tv's, cars (depending on how 'marvellous' and note-worthy it would be to the alien at a different level of technological advancement)

Not so different from the display dreams of feudal lords and other ancient and not-so ancient personalities really...

Given their invasion plans, it can be speculated that these aliens being long-lived have a small population and the only 'risk'-free way they can conquer planets is by infiltrating them as above.

Since the alien is said to dislike technology, it may be that:

a. he fears human technological advancement as means of defeating his kind. In this case, he will restrict technology access to humans perhaps pretending a dislike. This may be a possible cause why they are proceeding through their conquering plans so slowly.

b. the aliens are few in number but highly advanced. Our tech seems like peanuts to them. Their conquering plans are slow because they do not like direct confrontation and possible loss of alien life.

The things he displays would take all this into consideration.